# Icons are getting blurred in iPad and iPhone

Tags: adobe-photoshop, designers, interface-design, mobile, image-quality

All the icons i am designing for iPad & iPhone applications are looking good on my PC. But the same is looking blurred on any iPad or iPhone. Can any one please help/suggest something, is there anything I am doing wrong while designing in Photoshop

Comment: Might be you are using some other size dimensions (height/width) in your Ipad/iphone thats why they are getting blurred..please make it sure the dimension which your icon has,and which you are using in your code, both same in your code?

Comment: I am using same width and height.

Comment: I guess its completely related to your device, coz as you say everything goes fine with Photoshop on your desktop..

Comment: I have updated your question, you know how to design in photoshop i guess..but your question was not saying that..

Comment: @HappyNewYearToAll oops misread! Are you making the icon in all the correct sizes? There are something like 6 different ones...

Comment: I was wondering where your comment gone saying those "SO" words :D then I realized you deleted that, as I did :P

Comment: Oye Manisha lamba....

Comment: We need a lot more info. Are these web site icons? App icons? What dimensions are they being exported as? If it's a web page can we have a link to the page?

Answer (score 1):

Icons for iThings have to be created in multiple sizes. What appears to be blur, I suspect, is a problem with scaling. There is a good discussion [here](http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes) of all the necessary sizes (9 separate sizes) and the various quirky things that can happen to them when they are displayed on a particular device in a given context.

Be sure you're saving png files, not jpegs (especially super-compressed jpegs), and follow the [Apple HI guidelines for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).